# react native code push not updating changes in released APK

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I done all react native code push stuff . but when I run cmd = "appcenter codepush release-react -a xyz.abc-gmail.com/AppName -d Production". Then am getting message = "Successfully released an update containing the "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\code-push2021519-1588-5sorfr.dahyn\CodePush" directory to the "Production" deployment of the "Medicare" app.". but there is no any changes in installed APK. please help

here is codePush.js

```
import CodePush from "react-native-code-push";
import React from "react";

const CODE_PUSH_OPTIONS = {
  checkFrequency: CodePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
};

const withCodePush = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class WrappedApp extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
      CodePush.sync(
        { installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE },
        this.syncWithCodePush,
        null
      );
    }

    syncWithCodePush = (status) => {
      console.log("here is " + status);
    };

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent />;
    }
  }

  return CodePush(CODE_PUSH_OPTIONS)(WrappedApp);
};
export default withCodePush;
```

here is App.js

```
import withCodePush from "./codePush";


function registrationStackP({ navigation }) {
  return (
    screens......
  );
}

function registrationStackD({ navigation }) {
  return (
    screens......
  );
}

export default withCodePush(App);
```

please help